# How to generate a list (or even a sequence or a string) containing {x[1]==0&&x[2]==0&&...&&x[10]==0?

Tags: equation-solving, expression-manipulation, boxes

I need to solve a bunch of systems of `n` equations in `n` unknowns where `n` varies. I can do them, one by one, but I wish to automate the process.

The first equation equals 1 and the rest all equal zero. I currently type in each set of equations manually as follows. I have the `n` unknowns in a list: `list1 = {r,s,...,t}`. I have the expressions for the LHS in a 2nd list: `list2 = {expr1, ..., exprn}`. I write

```
sol = Solve[list2[[1]]==1 && list2[[2]]==0 ... && list2[[n]]==0, list1]
```

I would like to just type `Solve[expr, list]` where `expr` is something like

```
list2[[1]]==1 && list2[[2]]==0 ... && list2[[n]]==0.
```

I experimented with `Table`, `RowBox`, `BoxData`, and even `CellPrint` but I don't know enough to write an expression involving `&&` and `==` that will work inside the `Solve` function.

Comment: maybe `Solve[Thread[list2==Prepend[ConstantArray[0,Length[list2]-1],1]], list1]`?

Comment: `Solve[First@list2 == 1 && And @@ Thread[Rest@list2 == 0], list1]`

Comment: Both of these work perfectly. Thank you kglr and Bob Hanion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
Solve[Thread[list2 == Prepend[ConstantArray[0, Length[list2] - 1], 1]], list1]
```